# Collect acceleration data for 10 seconds using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have searched for a clear answer for this but I have not found one.

The *android application* will start the `AsyncTask` to collect *accelerometer data* once a button is pressed.

I want the `AsyncTask` to **stop after 10 seconds**. Basically trying to save a 10 second chunk of *acceleration data* to be process by another part of my application.

Is there a way to control the time the AsyncTask runs for?

Answer (score 0):

[public final Result get (long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) can be useful for you. e.g:

```
mTask.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```